# SharePoint Online - MDS broken?

Tags: sharepoint-online, minimal-download-strategy

I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed that minimal download strategy appears to be not working in SharePoint online? When switching between pages, the page appears to attempt to use MDS (the address bar points to /_layouts/15/start.aspx) but then a full page refresh occurs and a redirect to the actual page url.

I know that the new document libraries are probably not going to be currently compatible with the current version of MDS so I'm not talking about the switches between a site page and a library.

And no, the sites I've seen this on are plain vanilla, unmodified sites (no custom actions, script embeds etc that could mess up MDS). I've also tested against a number of tenants to which I have access.

I remember also noticing this earlier in the year, but it resolved itself after a few days. This time it seems to have been an issue for a couple of weeks.

Just looking to find out if anyone else has noticed this?

Comment: I haven't but I haven't really been looking tbh, might behoove you to open a support case in the Admin portal.

Comment: Yep, I've already done that. Did a screen sharing session with a guy; unfortunately he was not really aware of what MDS actually is, so it was a little hard to explain the expected behaviour. I was clicking links and pages were changing, so of course he was thinking it was normal. He is going to try to escalate, will see where it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joy of Cloud Updates...

MDS is not broken, it is gone, the `asyncDeltaManager` is not loaded

> is this a result of the July 1st update `16.0.5423.x` ??

I can't tell, I don't have any Tenants on older builts

I presume it is because of more upcoming 'New Experiences'

Question: did you have functionality relying on MDS, which now does not work anymore?

Comment: No, I'd never have anything depend on MDS given it's a feature that can be turned off anyway. I've just been trying to ensure my scripts are always compliant.

Comment: It looks like the brain-space occupied with MDS knowledge can be cleared out; FYI there is no SP Object or JSOM or CSR on those New Experiences either... SharePoint future starts with an almost empty brain ;-)